# Test mocked instance while leaving its methods executable

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

I have something similar to the code below where I want to test some flow in `ClassToTest` using `pytest_mock`. To do that, I need to pass it an object that implements some specific methods, in this case `method1` and `method2` in `MockClass`. After the `ClassToTest` instance execution using `run()`, I want to check if some methods in `mock_class` were called or not while those method must remain executable. What is the way to do that?

```
import ClassToTest


class MockClass:
    def method1(self):
        return "method1 output"
    
    def method2(self):
        return "method2 output"


def test_class_to_test():
    mock_class = MockClass()
    class_to_test = ClassToTest(mock_class)
    class_to_test.run()
    
    mock_class.method1.assert_called()
    mock_class.method2.assert_not_called()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to mock the output of these methods, the easiest way is to just use a `MagicMock` and do the patching there:

```py
def test_class_to_test(mocker):
    mock_class = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_class.method1.return_value = "method1 output"
    mock_class.method2.return_value = "method2 output"
    class_to_test = ClassToTest(mock_class)
    class_to_test.run()

    mock_class.method1.assert_called()
    mock_class.method2.assert_not_called()
```

(using `mocker` here as you seem to use `pytest-mock`)

This way you dont' need a separate class for mocking.
You could also move the mock into a separate fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_class(mocker):
    mock_class = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_class.method1.return_value = "method1 output"
    mock_class.method2.return_value = "method2 output"
    yield mock_class


def test_class_to_test(mock_class):
    class_to_test = ClassToTest(mock_class)
    class_to_test.run()

    mock_class.method1.assert_called()
    mock_class.method2.assert_not_called()
```

If you need the methods to have arguments, it gets a bit more complicated - you can use `side_effect` with a respective function instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_class(mocker):
    def method1(foo):
        return "method1 output " + foo

    def method2(foo):
        return "method2 output " + foo

    mock_class = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_class.method1.side_effect = method1
    mock_class.method2.side_effect = method2
    yield mock_class
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it when `method1` and `method2` have inputs?

Comment: If you mean, if they have arguments, I added this to the answer.